# Image in PDF cut off: How to make a canvas fit entirely in a PDF page?

Tags: canvas, html2canvas, jspdf

When placing the canvas in the PDF using the jspdf library makes the image cut off.

```
html2canvas(myContainer, {background: 'red'}).then (canvas) ->
  imgData = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg', 1.0)
  window.open(imgData) # this is just a test that opens the image in a new tab and it displays nicely, the entire image
  pdf = new jsPDF("l", "pt", "b1") # tried a variety of formats but no luck
  pdf.addImage(imgData, 'JPEG', 0, 0)
  pdf.save('file.pdf') # the generated pdf that contains the image gets trimmed
```

Does anyone have any ideas how to make the canvas fit?

Comment: Any errors in the console?

Comment: @KenFyrstenberg no errors. everything goes fine from making a canvas out of the HTML and putting it in the PDF, it's just that it doesn't fit entirely and ends up cutting the rest of the canvas/image off like it doesn't care.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try setting the width and height of the image as well (in any case, there is little documentation for addImage it seems):

```
var pdf = new jsPDF("l", "mm", "a4");
var imgData = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg', 1.0);

// due to lack of documentation; try setting w/h based on unit
pdf.addImage(imgData, 'JPEG', 10, 10, 180, 150);  // 180x150 mm @ (10,10)mm
```

Comment: You just saved my weekend!

Comment: I've tried in mine, I'm using portrait view, set `var pdf = new jsPDF("p", "mm", "a4");` and `pdf.addImage(imgData, 'JPEG', 10, 10, 150, 180);` and this doesn't work :( any suggestion?

Answer (score 9):

Here's the solution that worked for me, for my use case:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var imgData = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
var pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', [canvas.width, canvas.height]);
var pdfWidth = pdf.internal.pageSize.getWidth();
var pdfHeight = pdf.internal.pageSize.getHeight();
pdf.addImage(imgData, 'PNG', 0, 0, pdfWidth, pdfHeight);
pdf.save("mypdf.pdf");
```

Answer (score 6):

I have a solution for you :

```
function saveImageToPdf(idOfHtmlElement)
{
   var fbcanvas = document.getElementById(idOfHtmlElement);
   html2canvas($(fbcanvas),
        {

            onrendered: function (canvas) {

                var width = canvas.width;
                var height = canvas.height;
                var millimeters = {};
                millimeters.width = Math.floor(width * 0.264583);
                millimeters.height = Math.floor(height * 0.264583);

                var imgData = canvas.toDataURL(
                    'image/png');
                var doc = new jsPDF("p", "mm", "a4");
                doc.deletePage(1);
                doc.addPage(millimeters.width, millimeters.height);
                doc.addImage(imgData, 'PNG', 0, 0);
                doc.save('WebSiteScreen.pdf');
            }
        });
}
```

The things you have to do is:

1. Convert pixels to mm.
2. Delete first not resized properly page
3. Create a new one with good size in mm.
4. Save image.

Comment: Great solution. How did you get to the converion number 0.264583 ? My understanding at the moment is that you need the dpi value of the pdf to determine the conversion number.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like the size of the image and page size of the pdf is not the same. you can either set the page size ie. add a page with defined height and width similar to the image or you can set options for the image while adding it into the pdf.

Example for method 1 : [Answered above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42295522/11403256)
Example for method 2:

```
    var pdf = new jsPDF("l", "mm", "a4");   //orientation: landscape
    var imgData = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
    var width = pdf.internal.pageSize.getWidth();
    var height = pdf.internal.pageSize.getHeight();
    pdf.addImage(imgData, 'PNG', 0, 0, width, height); 
    pdf.save('download.pdf');
```

Answer (score 0):

I specified something like this. Looks gd. Pls try:

```
html2canvas(input)  
          .then((canvas) => {  
            var imgWidth = 350;  
            var imgHeight = canvas.height * imgWidth / canvas.width;  
            const imgData = canvas.toDataURL('image/png', 1.0);  
            const pdf = new jsPDF('l', 'mm', 'a4')  
            
            pdf.addImage(imgData, 'JPEG', -25 , 5,imgWidth , imgHeight);  

            pdf.save("download.pdf");  
          });
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution for full width auto height that extends page height where needed

```
  const document = new jsPDF();
  const imgProps= document.getImageProperties(imageToAdd);
  const width = document.internal.pageSize.getWidth();
  const ratio = width/ imgProps.width;
  const height = ratio * imgProps.height;
  document.internal.pageSize.height = height;
  document.addImage(this.doc, 'PNG', 0, 0, width, height);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the code that worked for me:

```js
const doc = new jsPDF();

let width = doc.internal.pageSize.getWidth();
let height = doc.internal.pageSize.getHeight();

doc.addImage(imgData, 'JPEG', 0, 0, width, height);
```