# How to use FabricJS and jsPDF to export in 300 dpi?

Tags: javascript, pdf, canvas, fabricjs, jspdf

I'm trying to figure out how to export my canvas in 300 dpi on pdf.

I found some articles that show how to calculate 300dpi for pixels on canvas ([What is the best practice to export canvas with high quality images?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17025603/what-is-the-best-practice-to-export-canvas-with-high-quality-images)) as well as convert it to pdf using jsPDF ([Convert canvas to PDF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23681325/convert-canvas-to-pdf))

However, I'm not very sure how I can design something on a 10cm x 6cm canvas and export it in 300dpi. Using the formula...

```
10cm * 300dpi / 2.54 = 1181px // width
6cm * 300dpi / 2.54 = 709px // height
```

I've created a canvas at 1181px width and 709px height.

However, when I create object using Fabric.js with the height 100px by 100px, I get this on the canvas.

[image]

However, when I export it using jspdf... I get this...

[image]

Here are my codes...

```
  // create a wrapper around native canvas element (with id="c")
  var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas');
  canvas.backgroundColor = "white";

  // create a rectangle object
  var rect = new fabric.Rect({
    left: 0,
    top: 0,
    fill: 'red',
    width: 100,
    height: 100
  });

  // "add" rectangle onto canvas
  canvas.add(rect);

  $('#export-btn').click(function(){
    var imgData = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg", 1.0);
    var pdf = new jsPDF('l', 'mm', [60,100]);

    pdf.addImage(imgData, 'JPEG', 0, 0);
    var download = document.getElementById('download');

    pdf.save("download.pdf");
  });
```

Should i resize the imgData exported from canvas.toDataURL() before passing it to jsPDF?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29578721/image-in-pdf-cut-off-how-to-make-a-canvas-fit-entirely-in-a-pdf-page/29578919#29578919