# jsPDF is not rendering SVG images right

Tags: javascript, jspdf

I am trying to take a screenshot of a webpage using jsPDF which have dynamically created SVGs but it is not rendering the SVG diagrams correctly.

Here is what I have done:

```js
 function genPDF() {
   html2canvas(document.getElementById("full_page"), {
     onrendered: function(canvas) {
       var imgData = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
       var pdf     = new jsPDF("p", "mm", "a4");
       var width   = pdf.internal.pageSize.width;
       var height  = pdf.internal.pageSize.height;
       
       pdf.addImage(imgData, 'svg', 0, 0, width, height);
       pdf.save('full_report.pdf');
     }
   });
 }
```

Here `full_page` is the whole section of the page. How can I get the SVG correctly?

Comment: Could you try image/svg+xml instead of image/png?

Comment: @MaartenWolfsen didn't worked :(

Comment: Could you add a screenshot?

Comment: Please check the screenshots @MaartenWolfsen

Comment: See if this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29578721/image-in-pdf-cut-off-how-to-make-a-canvas-fit-entirely-in-a-pdf-page/29578919#29578919

Answer (score 0):

try that:

```
pdf.addImage(imgData, 'png', 0, 0, width, height);
```

Your image is an "image/png":

```
var imgData = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
```