# How to add header/footer with dynamic pages using jsPDF without using fromHTML

Tags: jspdf

I am not using fromHTML, as it has limited modification options. I've also included image in header with base64 which is working fine.

My concern is with header and footer which should be on all pages of PDF. I don't want to use addPage() method as PDF's data will be dynamic.

Really in need for the answer. Much appreciate the support, thanks.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42832164/how-to-add-watermark-in-pdf-genereted-from-jspdf/42834665#42834665